# invoke parent onPress method when interact with children

Tags: react-native

I want to trigger parent component onPress method AND the children onPress method when press on the child component.

is there a way to do that WITHOUT passing the parent's method the children?

(this because I use it as a container for clients' components without their needs to make changes in their code)

example:

this will trigger both `console.log('parent pressed')}` and `console.log('children pressed')}`

```
        <Pressable style={{margin: 20, backgroundColor: 'red'}} onPress={() => console.log('parent pressed')}>
          <Button label={'press here'} onPress={() => console.log('children pressed')}/>
        </Pressable>
```

picture:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what you can do, you can pass same function to parent/child.

```
eventAction = () => {console.log("result of both events")}
```

inside render()

```
<Pressable style={{margin: 20, backgroundColor: 'red'}} onPress={this.eventAction}>
              <Button label={'press here'} onPress={this.eventAction}/>
    </Pressable>
```

and I think there is no need of Button component inside Pressable , you can use Text component inside it.

EDITED :

```
parentAction = () => {console.log("result of 1st events")}
childAction = () => {console.log("result of 2nd events")}


<Pressable style={{margin: 20, backgroundColor: 'red'}} onPress={()=>{this.parentAction()}}>
              <Button label={'press here'} onPress=onPress={()=>{this.parentAction(); this.childAction()}}/>
    </Pressable>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I want to make BOTH onPress invoke WITHOUT the need to change something in the child component.. about the Button nested in Pressable, agree - this is just for the example.

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think if I am getting right then it would help ...

Comment: still, it requires the children to specify the parent action. I have a component that I'm not in charge of as the child component so I'm looking for a solution that is invisible to the child component.